Deep Q learning or deep Reinforcement learning :take action but state stay always same

hello i implemented a dqn model to solve the sat problem for cnf data. Now the cnn model works correctly and also there is no problem with the agent part. But when I run the train code, it shows that no matter what action take,state and next state don't change. Could this be a problem with the agent part. Or is it the logic error in the environment that I need to change. I am using the dpll algorithm.
